# Launching Windows Store apps that are calling Camera Capture UI on its previous state

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, windows-store-apps

I have searching and trying to find a workaround of relaunching app that using camera handle.
I am creating a Windows Store application that can be launched using protocol. Currently, I am using WPF app to launch the protocol.

The Windows Store app is using CameraCaptureUI, I tested to switch apps, and relaunch the Windows Store app using the WPF apps. It gives me an access denied because its recreate the CameraCaptureUI and show it again while there is still an existing CameraCaptureUI.

I tried to not calling the `CaptureFileAsync` method on the second launch, but it leaves me with no more capture UI and resulting in a null file returned instead.

How to let me relaunch apps with the previous execution state running that uses the CameraCaptureUI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I already found a work around on this issue.

The first thing that I do is ensuring that the state of the object is still the same and I store references to the async method used to capture the camera. Whenever I want to capture it again, I could simply cancel the first operation and replace it with the new operation.